# Password Protected Page Title

Tags: pages, page-template, password

I'm currently using Sage 8.5.1 theme and have some password protected pages. The client would like to have the word "Protected" removed but not the title. I've used this code snippet

```
add_filter( 'protected_title_format', 'remove_protected_text' );
function remove_protected_text() {
    return __('%s');
}
```

But it removes the title also. I've looked and everywhere seems to use basically the same snippet of code. I've posed this question on Roots Discourse and they said it's not theme specific and to post my question here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to translate the title, so there's no need to use __() here and you won't translate '%s', because that's a placeholder.

```
add_filter( 'protected_title_format', 'remove_protected_text' );
function remove_protected_text() {
    return '%s';
}
```

should work.

Comment: I would also add in the [`private_title_format`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/private_title_format/) filter hook too for good measure.

Comment: This did not work. Entire title removed.

Comment: In that case, something else is happening in your system. I've tested it in a local installation and it worked just fine. It also makes sense [looking at the code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L130). Is the title still removed if you replace %s with anything else?

Answer (score 0):

use a filter function:
Copy and paste whichever you prefer into your theme functions.php

```
<?php
function the_title_trim($title){
$pattern[0] = '/Protected:/';
$replacement[0] = ''; // Enter some text to put in place of Protected:
return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $title);
}
add_filter('the_title', 'the_title_trim');
?>
```

Comment: This seems like a more complicated version than the previously posted. answer.

Comment: This one throws a php error.

Comment: If you are putting in php tag it will shows an error before this code just close the previous php code link this:  ?> add this tag before the code mentioned above.